# using variable to parse data with D3js when reading in from csv file

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am new to D3js and would like to use it in a dynamic fashion, that is, based on the data series that the user wants to chart, I want to be able to pass variables to a function that are used to parse the data when extracted from a csv file.

The code segment from examples I have found all show reading data from a csv or tsv file as:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));
```

where the csv header/key is specified. I would like to replace the d.date and d.close with variable (ie, varX and varY) that will be passed to a function so the data displayed can vary. The function structure I was thinking of was:

```
 function BarChart(filePath,varX,varY,loc){

  //put in the code above modified to use varX and varY in place of d.date and d.close
  //other code required to create the chart
  }
```

I have tried a few different ways (using d.varX, or just varX) and done a lot of reading on the web to find something but have not been able to make this work.  I'm not sure if D3js is even meant to be used in this way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Lars, thanks for pointing me to the answer I was after! I think I was using the wrong key words to search. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a funtion like that:

```
  graph({height: 200, width:400, id: "ccag", xE:d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["I", " II", "III", "IV", "V"]),
    data: [[{ x: 0, y: 109117 },{ x: 1, y: 22546 },{ x: 2, y: 29449 },{ x: 3, y: 43711 },{ x: 4, y: 26604 }],[{ x: 0, y: 7481 },{ x: 1, y: 5328 },{ x: 2, y: 10315 },{ x: 3, y: 6218 },{ x: 4, y: 4330 }]],
    color:[["#1c3848"],["#36a8e1"]]
    })();
```

then your function to draw the graph:

```
function graph(a) {
  return function () {
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 35},
    w = a.width - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = a.height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    fnum = d3.format(",");

    //Original data
    var ccad = a.data;
    var stack = d3.layout.stack();

    //Data, stacked
    stack(ccad);
.....
.....
```

Or you can pass file name to function:

```
graph({file:"newTSV.tsv"})
```

then on your function:

```
function graph(a) {
  return function () {
    d3.tsv(a.file, function(data) { ....
```